# Should I delete a question where problem has been avoided?

Tags: discussion, questions

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829788/check-if-session-has-started) yesterday about a problem I had with sessions in `ASP.NET`.

Since the project has changed a little bit, I'm now using `Windows Authentication` instead of database-linked form authentication and then I don't need an answer anymore.

I should delete the question, but the thing is, I don't know if someone else could have the same problem and then reaches this question (with no answers yet, but perhaps there will be some when the time comes).

Should I **let it** as it is or should I **delete it**, having in mind that if someone has the same problem, he will ask another question ?

Comment: Since there are no answers on it, if I were no longer able or willing to evaluate answers that might come up, I'd delete the question, and let someone for whom the problem is a live one deal with evaluating the answers they'll get to the question they'll post. This is a personal preference, not a site rule.